# Getting jsdoc and intellisense from custom cypress commands

Tags: javascript, cypress, jsdoc

I am currently setting up cypress for my project, and thought it would be a good idea to create a bunch of commands to keep the tests more readable.

so I added this in `support/commands.js`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
  "signup",
  ({ email, displayName, password, companyName, registrationKey, stub }) => {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/signup").wait(1);
    if (stub) {
      cy.intercept("POST", "/signup.json", stub);
    }
    cy.get("#email-address").type(email);
    cy.get("#displayName").type(displayName);
    if (companyName) cy.get("#companyName").type(companyName);
    cy.get("#password").type(password);
    cy.get("#repeat-password").type(password);
    cy.get("button").click().wait(1);
    cy.get("#error-message").should("not.exist");
  }
);
```

and I can use it in my specs and it does what it should.
However I am not getting any sort of intellisense on the command when writing my tests.

ex

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
describe("test", () => {
  it("can signup", () => {
    cy.signup({
      email: "mail@mail.com",
      displayName: "cool_dude",
      password: "Password1",
      companyName: "Not a scam AB",
    });
  });
});
```

And I have to refer to the `commands.js` file to see what options I have for the `signup` function.

So I am wondering if it is possible to add jsdoc to custom cypress commands, and if so, how?

Comment: I think you have to create a file in the support folder (`cypress/support/index.d.ts`) as stated in the documentation: [triple slash](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/intelligent-code-completion.html#Triple-slash-directives)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VSCode, try using the Cypress Helper extension. It will handle some of this for you. After installing it, go into the extension settings, scroll to the botton, and you'll see the *Type Definition On Save* setting. Check that box, and it will generate the *.d.ts file entries based on your custom commands, every time you save.

After that, creating Intellisense text is as easy as writing JSDoc comments above your custom command, like so:

```
/**
 * Logs in the user
 */
Cypress.Commands.add('logIn', (email) => {
  doSomeLoginStuff()
})
```

Saving this results in the following code being added to a d.ts file in the same folder:

```
/**
 * Logs in the user
 */
logIn(email: any): Chainable<any>
```

Comment: Cypress Helper was a life saver in my case. Everything is in JS, my other option was to convert to Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to do it is to follow the official guide [Types for Custom Commands](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Types-for-Custom-Commands). It's not JSDoc solution but it works.

```
// cypress/support/index.ts
Cypress.Commands.add('dataCy', (value) => {
  return cy.get(`[data-cy=${value}]`)
})


// in cypress/support/index.ts
// load type definitions that come with Cypress module
/// <reference types="cypress" />
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      /**
       * Custom command to select DOM element by data-cy attribute.
       * @example cy.dataCy('greeting')
       */
      dataCy(value: string): Chainable<Element>
    }
  }
}
```